# How to Initialise a Field of Custom Objects That Do Not Have a Default Constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, object, sparse-matrix, allocation

As the title indicates, I'm trying to allocate memory for an array of default objects that don't have a default constructor (meaning I can't use `new` - I think). To be more exact, I'm trying to implement a "Sparse Matrix" using the following header blueprint:

```
class SparseMatrix {
    SparseVector* m_rows;
public:
    SparseMatrix(int rows, int columns);
}
```

Now this is for a university practice and thus, I can't really change method signatures or class properties here. I know about "Vector", but I don't think I can use it here if I want to keep `SparseVector* m_rows`.

So I want to allocate memory for my array in the constructor of the matrix, but I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

EDIT: SparseVector has a custom constructor that gives it a size.

Comment: Of course you can specify arguments to `new` :)

Comment: Are you saying that `SparseVector` has no default constructor?

Comment: I'm trying to allocate an _array_ of objects, though. Does `new` still work with arguments in that case? If so, how? I've been (quite desperately) trying `this->m_rows = new SparseVector(columns)[rows];`, but it throws a compiler error.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's way different if it has no default constructor, but has user-defined, vs. no constructors at all. You need to be more specific and provide the class definition of SparseVector if it has one.

Comment: @VaughnCato: Yeah, that's right. And even if it had one, it would have to assume a size (for example 0), which is not what I want in this case.

Comment: Is it possible to change the size of the vector after it is constructed?

Comment: It should be, since I've overridden the assignment operator of `SparseVector`.

Comment: I don't think there is any easy way to do this.  Can you add members to the class?

Comment: It seems like you would at least have to be able to add a destructor.

Comment: I should be able to add both members and a destructor.